# inner product of positive semi definite symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a  positive semi definite symmetric matrix $X$, $(n\times n)$.

let $X=vv^T$ s.t $\|v\|=1$.

I came to a point where I am stuck to show which is:

$v^TYv=\langle X,Y\rangle$ (How to show this equality?)- inner product is of symmetric matrices

and $Y$ is a symmetric matrix $(n\times n)$

Comment: What does $< X, Y >$ mean?

Comment: Is it $\langle X,Y \rangle =tr(XY)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the inner product is $\langle X,Y\rangle = \operatorname{tr} (X^TY)= \operatorname{tr}(XY)$ ($X,Y$ are symmetric), then $v^TYv=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n Y_{ij}v_iv_j =\sum\limits_{i,j} Y_{ij}X_{ij} = \operatorname{tr}(XY)=\langle X,Y\rangle$, because you have that $X_{ij}=v_iv_j$.